# Why isn't the foreign key field of a Many-to-One relationship being set on insert?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

My Spring web application allows users to update "Employee" records to change the fields or add new "Phone" records related to this "Employee" record. However, when the "Employee" record is submitted for update after adding a new "Phone" record, it's throwing a SQL error exception.

The problem is that the "employee_id" foreign key on "Phone" table to the "Employee" table isn't set in the eventual SQL insert statement submitted to the database. However, in the "PhoneEntity" JPA entity object that is referenced by the updated/merged "EmployeeEntity" object, the property associated with the `employee_id` database field isn't null, it's set to the "EmployeeEnity" Object being updated/merged.

From my understanding of JPA, having the entity property associated with a database field should set it when the insert statement for the entity's record is submitted to the database, but in this case it isn't which is causing this error.

I've tried stepping through with a debugger, and I have verified that the created `PhoneEntity` object is a member of `EmployeeEntity`'s `phones` property, and that the same `PhoneEntity`'s `employee` property is set to the same `EmployeeEntity` object (with the same object IDs) in a bidirectional relationship.

I've also set the `hibernate.show_sql=true` to see the SQL statement being submitted to the database and it includes the statement (with the ellipses being more fields):

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        phone
        (id, employee_id, ...) 
    values
        (?, ?, ...)
```

Which means that it is inserting a new `phone` for the new `PhoneEntity` object.

After trying to running this insert statement it gives the SQL error "Column 'employee_id' cannot be null". However like I said before, I've checked with the debugger and the `employee` property is indeed set to the `EmployeeEntity` object.

this is a simplified example of what my code looks like:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class EmployeeEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<PhoneEntity> phones = new HashSet<>();

...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
public class PhoneEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    private EmployeeEntity employee;

...
}
```

With tables that have the structure created by the following SQL statements.

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
...
);

CREATE TABLE phone (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_id INT NOT NULL,
...
    FOREIGN KEY(employee_id) REFERENCES employee(id)
);
```

And the following is where it actually submits the updates to the entity manager to make updates to the database.

```java
    public void update(EmployeeDomain employee) {
        EmployeeEntity entity = employeeDomainToEntity.transform(employee)
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }
```

The `EmployeeEntity` and `PhoneEntity` objects are created by converting similar domain objects that were in turn deserialized from a http request. I'd include more of this section of the code but, as I've mentioned, I've already confirmed with my debugger that the actual entity objects being submitted to the merge are already in the form that we expected with the `phones` fields and `employee` fields being set correctly, so the end entities should be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the official [JPA specification document](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) (version 2.1) in section "*3.2.7.1 Merging Detached Entity State*" (page 85) we find:

> For all entities `Y` referenced by relationships from `X` having the cascade element value `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL`, `Y` is merged recursively as `Y'`. For all such `Y` referenced by `X`, `X'` is set to reference `Y'`. (Note that if X is managed then X is the same object as X'.)

This explains that you are lacking `cascade=MERGE` for the annotation of the `phones` field.

As proposed in *thanh ngo*'s answer, the aforementioned definition (or: explanation) thus translates to:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="employee", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Set<PhoneEntity> phones = new HashSet<>();
```

Alternatively, you could also make use of `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`. However, this would also include operations such as `CascadeType.REMOVE` which might not always be intended.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using merge.
The cascade type setting for the entity should be:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="employee", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<PhoneEntity> phones = new HashSet<>();
```